# project reference won't compile 'should be reference'

Tags: c#, .net

In the following new test project I've created for testing the web code I have the following error when trying to compile my code.

Not sure what this means because I've added the reference to the project including the controllers into the test project??

Any ideas

Many thanks,
James

[image: error message]

**Error message**

```
Error   330 The type 'Web.Supporting.BaseControllers.PowerController' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Web.Areas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    C:\Power\Test.Unit.Web.Portal\Controllers\SearchProductControllerTests.cs   39  13  Test.Unit.Web.Portal
```

**UPDATE**

Tried adding system.web.mvc into the test project although I can't see it, see image below

**UPDATE**

Found it by looking at an existing test project.  Can't see it in the dialog (???) but I located it here: C:..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll

[image]

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Is your controller sitting inside an MVC area?

Comment: mvc is actually a class library

Comment: Is the assembly you are referencing for a higher .NET Framework version than your project?

Comment: Thanks I didn't actually compile it because of the hover over message.  But when I compiled it it did actually say to include the .areas dll which I have and some progress has been made..  But I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include reference to `Web.Areas` library which it is asking for? If not add it.

If you already have a reference to it then "Target Framework Version" will be the problem. If your current project is targeted to lesser version than the referenced assemblies this will happen. Ex: If current project targets to .net4.0 and `Web.Areas` is targeted to .net4.5 this error will appear.

To fix it you may need to downgrade all other projects version or upgrade current project's version.

Comment: where do I specify the target version please?  In the  properties of the dll reference?  (I couldn't see the option when doing that..)

Comment: Yes in project properties only. [This should help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Comment: its saying I need to add a reference to system.web.mvc - if I click on 'add references' I can't see it anywhere in the reference manager/ com or assemblies or solution tabs..?

Comment: Yes, If your classes use MVC then you need to add that also. You can add it via `Right click -> Reference -> Add Reference`

Comment: It should be in Extensions tab, currently you're checking in Framework tab

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I added a reference into the test project for the PowerController dll and also the system.web.mvc.  Note: system.web.mvc is in the extension tab of the 'add reference' dialog.